# Save Predicted images in CNN network

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I wrote a CNN network with Tensorflow which works properly and I want to check classified images during the testing stage.

In my dataset, I have 5 different categories, during the test stage I am looking for a way to save classified images in a new folder for each category to check the results from my net make or not sense.

This is the whole of my code in the test stage:

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.0001, 'Learning rate for adam optimizer')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_classes', 3, 'Number of classes')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 128, 'Batch size')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('keep_prob', 0.8, 'Dropout keep probability')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_channel',3 , 'Image channel, RGB=3, Grayscale=1')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('img_size', 80, 'Size of images')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('test_file', 'data/test.txt', 'Test dataset file')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

checkpoint_dir = '/home/xyrio/Desktop/classier/training/checkpoints/model_epoch.ckpt89'


def main(_):

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.img_size, FLAGS.img_size, FLAGS.num_channel], name='x')
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, FLAGS.num_classes], name='y_true')
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=1)

filter_size_conv1 = 3
num_filters_conv1 = 32

filter_size_conv2 = 3
num_filters_conv2 = 32

filter_size_conv3 = 3
num_filters_conv3 = 64

filter_size_conv4 = 3
num_filters_conv4 = 128

filter_size_conv5 = 3
num_filters_conv5 = 256

fc_layer_size = 512
fc_layer_size2 = 128

def create_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean=0, stddev=0.01))

def create_biases(size):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape=[size]))

def create_convolutional_layer(input, num_input_channels, conv_filter_size, num_filters, useBatchNorm=False,
                               usePooling=True):

    weights = create_weights(shape=[conv_filter_size, conv_filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters])
    biases = create_biases(num_filters)
    layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input, filter=weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    layer += biases
    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

    if useBatchNorm == True:
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)

    if usePooling:
        layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    return layer

def create_flatten_layer(layer):

    layer_shape = layer.get_shape()
    num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()
    layer = tf.reshape(layer, [-1, num_features])

    return layer

def create_fc_layer(input, num_inputs, num_outputs, useRelu=True, useDropout=False):
    weights = create_weights(shape=[num_inputs, num_outputs])
    biases = create_biases(num_outputs)

    layer = tf.matmul(input, weights) + biases
    if useRelu:
        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

    if useDropout == True:
        layer = tf.nn.dropout(layer, keep_prob=FLAGS.keep_prob)
    return layer

layer_conv1 = create_convolutional_layer(x, FLAGS.num_channel, filter_size_conv1, num_filters_conv1,
                                         useBatchNorm=True, usePooling=True)
layer_conv2 = create_convolutional_layer(layer_conv1, num_filters_conv1, filter_size_conv2, num_filters_conv2,
                                         useBatchNorm=True, usePooling=True)
layer_conv3 = create_convolutional_layer(layer_conv2, num_filters_conv2, filter_size_conv3, num_filters_conv3,
                                         useBatchNorm=True, usePooling=True)
layer_conv4 = create_convolutional_layer(layer_conv3, num_filters_conv3, filter_size_conv4, num_filters_conv4,
                                         useBatchNorm=True, usePooling=True)
layer_conv5 = create_convolutional_layer(layer_conv4, num_filters_conv4, filter_size_conv5, num_filters_conv5,
                                         useBatchNorm=True, usePooling=True)

layer_flat = create_flatten_layer(layer_conv5)

layer_fc1 = create_fc_layer(layer_flat, layer_flat.get_shape()[1:4].num_elements(), fc_layer_size, useRelu=True,
                            useDropout=False)
layer_fc2 = create_fc_layer(layer_fc1, fc_layer_size, fc_layer_size2, useRelu=True, useDropout=True)
layer_fc3 = create_fc_layer(layer_fc2, fc_layer_size2, FLAGS.num_classes, useRelu=False)

y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(layer_fc3, name='y_pred', axis=1)
y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)


correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_pred_cls, y_true_cls)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

saver = tf.train.Saver()

test_preprocessor = BatchPreprocessor(dataset_file_path=FLAGS.test_file, num_classes=FLAGS.num_classes,
                                     output_size=[FLAGS.img_size, FLAGS.img_size])

test_batches_per_epoch = np.floor(len(test_preprocessor.labels) / FLAGS.batch_size).astype(np.int16)

conf_mat = tf.confusion_matrix(y_true_cls,y_pred_cls,FLAGS.num_classes)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_dir)

    # Start Testing
    test_acc = 0.
    test_count = 0
    cm_total = None
    for _ in range(test_batches_per_epoch):
        batch_tx, batch_ty = test_preprocessor.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
        acc, conf_m = sess.run([accuracy, conf_mat],
                               feed_dict={x: batch_tx, y_true: batch_ty})


        if cm_total is None:
            cm_total = conf_m
        else:
            cm_total += conf_m

        test_acc += acc
        test_count += 1

    test_acc /= test_count
    print("{} Testing Accuracy = {:.2%}".format(datetime.now(), test_acc))


    test_preprocessor.reset_pointer()
print(cm_total)
```

This code is for test data, as you can see I restored checkpoint which I saved during training and validating, and after that, I used the best checkpoint for predict on my test data.

`batch_tx` is my test data and `batch_ty` is my test label.

is anyone have an idea how can I do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'll need to step inside your sess.run - you're feeding a whole batch of images to the network and getting accuracy, confusion matrix in return (summing the confusion matrix). Is your batch_size = 1? If not, you need your session to return the predicted labels *in order* (so run it in one thread!), then you can use matplotlib or PIL to turn the RGB(?) data in the batch into .png or .jpg files, naming each file with its predicted label.

Comment: Hey, can you explain in more details how can I do it? my batch_size is 128.

Comment: Ok. Your batch file is labels (batch_tx?) and data (batch_ty). The data is *likely* planar, normalised, RGB, so take the data, transform it into numpy array, rearrange the axes (maybe) and save using matplotlib (there are questions for this). Somewhere in your session (I don't have the code, so I guess), you'll call tf.confusion_matrix, look at the arguments for this to get your predicted labels. Feed the predicted labels back through to where you can access the batch dict and use them to name your files.

Comment: Some questions that might get you a good answer if you edit your question: What is your data file and how did you make it? Where are your predicted labels (show code for those, too)? And it might be worth looking at TensorBoard, if your code is suitable for it.

Comment: I have edited my post and upload whole on my test stage code. My data are images with labels (which I create by my self. 0 for birds, 1 for dogs, 2 for cats) for 3 different categories.

Comment: y_pred_cls will contain your predicted class labels, it should be a tensor of dimensions 1 x batch size. x is your RGB data. At the end of every batch (where you sum the confusion matrix), iterate over y_pred_cls as an array, and make a file name including pred class, true class and some index number, then use [imsave](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/102363/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave) to save the correct line of the batch array (making sure your axes are in the order h,w,c). FWIW, it *looks* like you might continue training during testing - does accuracy rise after >1 epoch test?

Comment: Hey @Pam, accuracy doesn't rise after >1 epoch. As you said y_pred_cls contain my predicted class labels. I add a line to my network exactly after confusion matrix summation: `sess.run(y_pred_cls, {x:batch_tx})` where batch_tx is my test RGB data and I got my predicted labels. Now, How am I going to find images from these labels and save them in a folder?

Comment: Hey @Pam, I think you are right about my test accuracy. during my training and validating, i got accuracy 75.62% on my validation set but when I used the saved checkpoint with the same validation data I have to get same accuracy (75.62%) but I am getting 76.188. Do you know the reason? I have edited my post as well (code part).

Comment: Is your number of tests perfectly divisible by your batch size? You can tell by summing everything in you confusion matrix and see if it adds up to your number of test images. If it isn't, it might be rounding up so for any single test run, you might have a few at the end that are different repeats? Also, remember to turn off drop out during testing. I don't see the back propagation/loss calculation in your current edit, so I don't think you're training. It might be worth asking a new question here to get more expert attention.

Comment: Thanks @Pam, I forgot to turn off dropout during my test stage as you said. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after the discussion above, you added the line

> sess.run(y_pred_cls, {x:batch_tx})

after your confusion matrix summation and now you have your predicted labels. Print them out in a format that you can turn into a np array for the code below. Provided your test code runs in a single thread, and it does not shuffle the test batches, you now have your predicted labels in the **same order** as the images appear in the input file. Assuming your input file is a .bin file, you should be able to extract images (using PIL) from it like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# your image dimensions here
width = 80
height = 80
channels = 3

# most labels are 1 byte
labelSize = 1
pixelSize = width * height * channels
recordSize = labelSize + pixelSize

label_names = ['cat', 'horse', 'dog'....]
predictions = [...] # put your predictions here

with open(inputFilename, "rb") as f:
    allTheData = np.fromfile(f, 'u1')

numRecords = allTheData.shape[0] / recordSize
allTheData = allTheData.reshape(numRecords, recordSize)

for idx, d in enumerate(allTheData):
   label = label_names[d[0]]
   rgbData = d[1:] #records are label first, then all pixel data and rgb


   predlabel = label_names[data_labels[idx]]


   filename = "{}_pred{}_actual{}.png".format(idx, predlabel, label)
   pictureA = rgbData.reshape(3, width, height)
   pictureA = np.swapaxes(pictureA,0,1)
   pictureA = np.swapaxes(pictureA,1,2)
   pictureA = np.ndarray.flatten(pictureA)

   imageA = Image.frombytes('RGB', (height, width), pictureA)
   #display(imageA)
   imageA.save(filename, "PNG")
```

Please note that the code above won't run until you add in proper label names and your predictions. Also, if the input file is a .csv, you will have to change the reading of it slightly.